# GetField for private property that returns Dictionary<Type,InternalType> and iterate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, system.reflection

**No problems getting at the type**

I am easily able to get at a nested property which is private by nature.

```
var modelConfigurationFieldInfo=
        _modelBuilder.Configurations.GetType().GetField(
            "_modelConfiguration",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
            |System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
            );

var modelConfiguration=
        modelConfigurationFieldInfo.GetValue(
            _modelBuilder.Configurations);

var entityConfigurationsFieldInfo=
        modelConfiguration.GetType().GetField(
            "_entityConfigurations",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
            |System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
            );

var entityConfigurations=
        entityConfigurationsFieldInfo.GetValue(modelConfiguration);
```

The problem is that `my _entityConfigurations` is a type of:

> **Dictionary`Type, System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration**

Note that the second type is internal and will not compile if I add it to the code. I have tried to cast to `dynamic` and `object` but both give me errors that say *the protection level is not allowed*.

I need a way to iterate the returned dicationary somehow.

Comment: Do you realize that even if you *can* do this, your code will be very brittle? You're basically relying on implementation details which could change in the next version.

Comment: Your right, and I also created a different strategy that works but this provides much less of a challenge to get the information. I would hope that the future versions make meta information from System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration available since it is so powerful. I think that this is an acceptable drawback in my case and that future upgrades and implementations will easy enough to handle.

Comment: @user303849: You can post your solution as an answer, make it Q&A style.

Comment: Can you describe this in detail. I have been given conflicting information on how I should continue to comment and answer my own question. Should I add to the original post or should I answer it in a new thread?

Comment: It's simple, just like you answer other questions, you can answer the question of yourself. If you thingk that what you posted in the question is a solution of this question, then you can move that part from the content of question to a new answer, and you can even accept the answer of yourself.

Comment: k thanks. I thought someone gave me a hard time before for doing that. Maybe I made a different mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found a solution!**

The dictionary key was type. There was another property that listed the types and was easily casted to **IEnumerable** since **System.Type** is public. Then in a foreach loop I was able to iterate the types. At the same time I could then call the internal "get_item" function of the dictionary passing the type as a parameter.

```
foreach(var type in types) 
{ 
    var data = entityConfigurations.GetType().GetMethod("get_Item")
                    .Invoke(new object[] { type });
    // Get more information here.
}
```

As Jon said below, this is very brittle because I am relying on internal implementation details subject to possible change in the future. This is not a good solution. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to get the information I need in a more elegant way so far. Maybe, I could let Microsoft know that I need this meta information exposed in a more public way  for the internal **EntityTypeConfiguration** type. But, until they listen I am left with few options.

This is a needed for a design-time tool to used for the collection of schema information set by the Code-First EntityFramework Fluent API. Prior to this I implemented a suite of wrapper classes that replace the **EntityTypeConfiguration** which followed a Wrapper-Delegation pattern where I could squirrel away the metadata I needed. There is more responsibility on both the myself and the user when using this pattern (ie. for Map Classes the user is forced to inherit from my custom implementation EntityTypeMetaConfiguration and for database context classes my [**DbMetaContext** : DbContext] is needed, not to mention the need for using a different overide for **OnModelCreating**).

Answer (score 1):

[Internal types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) are types which aren't exposed outside the assembly, and private [nested types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173120.aspx) are even more restricted.

As you stated that you've tried `dynamic` and `object` and got errors, here I'm using a example to represent your problem and for demonstration of how can you do that. I used a nested private class `System.Array.ArrayEnumerator` which comes with the framework instead.

```
public static partial class TestClass {
    public static void TestMethod() {
        var internalType=
                typeof(Array).GetNestedType(
                    "ArrayEnumerator", BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        var x=new SampleClass();
        var type=x.GetType();
        var bindingAttr=BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        var info=type.GetField("dict", bindingAttr);
        var dict=info.GetValue(x) as IDictionary<Type, object>;
        var arrayEnumerator=dict[internalType];
    }
}

partial class SampleClass {
    public SampleClass() {
        var internalType=
                typeof(Array).GetNestedType(
                    "ArrayEnumerator", BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        var invokeAttr=
                BindingFlags.CreateInstance|
                BindingFlags.Instance|
                BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        var array=new[] { 1, 2, 3 } as IList;
        var args=new object[] { array, 0, array.Count };

        var arrayEnumerator=
                internalType.InvokeMember(
                    ".ctor", invokeAttr, null, null, args);

        dict.Add(internalType, arrayEnumerator);
    }

    Dictionary<Type, object> dict=new Dictionary<Type, object>();
}
```

As I mentioned before, private nested types are more restricted. My code is not allowed to use `Array.ArrayEnumerator`, and I got no information of it at compile time, thus `object` is chosen. `dynamic` would not be helpful here, and will throw at runtime if I attempted to access the members of an `ArrayEnumerator`.

As you can see if you tested the code, it runs with no problem. The annoying thing is that you will need to do everything via reflection with the values of the dictionary.

Comment: Library `public class Basket 
    {
    public Basket()
        {
            BasketOfApples = new Dictionary<string, Apple>();
            BasketOfApples.Add("Birthday", new Apple() { Id = 0, Description = "Spartan" });
        }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        private Dictionary<String, Apple> BasketOfApples;
    }

    internal class Apple
    {
        public String Description { get; set; }
    }` then        `var dict=info.GetValue(basketInstance) as IDictionary<String, object>;` returns null (object is the wrong type)

Comment: The class `Apple` is inaccessible ouside your assembly, it should not be used as the type parameter here.

Comment: That's the whole point! I am trying to get at information that is internal to the assembly. The example given in this answer doesn't seem to address the problem I am facing.

Comment: @user303849: I thingk it's clear that *inaccessible* is you are not allowed to access the internal class with other assemblies by the compiler at compile time , however, you can use the type `object` to store the values with instances of the internal class, and access it as `object` outside the assembly; the members of the internal class are still possible be accessed via reflection at runtime. `object` is a bigger type to store them, the instances are of its real type at runtime.

Comment: [example solution](http://examples.jaimeweise.com/reflection/internal-problems.zip) if you want to see what I mean. Your solution is flawed.

Comment: @user303849: It's not kind of flawed. The solution that you found it works, probably because they are in the same assembly or the internal class is not used directly but via an interface which is not declared internal.

Comment: The example solution I created the code have two projects, one referencing the other--take a look--, are in two separate assemblies.

Comment: @user303849: What I said is like the `get_Item`, mostly it's the getter of the `indexer` such as a class implemented `IList` or directly provided an indexer itself.